# BHO plugin not working for IE7 on 64bit OS

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-7, 32bit-64bit, bho

The BHO which works smoothly on IE7 32bit XP/Vista does not work for IE7 on 64bt XP/Vista. I suspect the problem is with registering the BHO assembly. Can anyone has a good solution to make the BHO work for 64bit platform?

Thanks,

Datte

Comment: did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 2):

BHO are in-process components and you can not load 32bit dll to 64bit process.

You need to build a 64bit DLL for the 64 bit version of IE. The 32 bit version of IE on 64 bit Windows should work fine with your 32 bit BHO. If you are already building the BHO in 64bit, use ProcMon to see if your BHO has compatibility problems.